# Biztalk 2016 Fail to configuration Group

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I am facing to a problem during configuration Biztalk 2016 Group

[2017-01-06 16:25:27:0170  Error BtsCfg] The server has not been configured.
To configure the server, run the BizTalk Server Configuration wizard and configure the Group feature.
[2017-01-06 16:25:27:0186  Info BtsCfg] Instantiating IBTSMsgBoxPerformance object
[2017-01-06 16:25:27:0186  Info BtsCfg] Calling IBTSMsgBoxPerformance::UninstallArtifacts
Exception in CounterManager.UninstallArtifacts when uninstalling the perf counter instances. The exception details are: 
Source of exception: System
Message: Cannot delete Performance Category because this category is not registered or is a system category.
Stack trace:    at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Delete(String categoryName)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.MsgBoxPerfCounters.MgmtDbAccessEntity.UninstallInstances(Boolean regularUninstall)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.MsgBoxPerfCounters.CounterManager.UninstallArtifacts(Boolean regularUninstall, String logFileName)

I checked these things:

- SQL Server machine is accessable, SQL Server is running, TCP/IP is
  enabled.
- The installing user have Administrators right.
- MSDTC is configured on the Biztalk server machine and SQL Server machine,
  using DTCPing to test the connection from server to sql server
  machine is success.
- SSO had been successfully configured.

**Edit**:
First error line in log:

[2017-01-09 14:40:21:0833  Error BAMConfigWizExt] d:\bt\52584\private\source\monitoring\configuration\extention\helpers.h(2068): FAILED hr = 80004005
Then

[2017-01-09 14:42:34:0913  Error BtsCfg] d:\bt\52584\private\source\setup\btscfg\btswmi.cpp(436): FAILED hr = c0c025b3

[2017-01-09 14:42:34:0913  Error BtsCfg] Exception of type 'System.EnterpriseServices.TransactionProxyException' was thrown.

[2017-01-09 14:42:34:0913  Error BtsCfg] d:\bt\52584\private\source\setup\btscfg\btscfg.cpp(1820): FAILED hr = c0c025b3

[2017-01-09 14:42:34:0913  Info BtsCfg] Entering function: CBtsCfg::UnConfigureFeature

[2017-01-09 14:42:34:0913  Info BtsCfg]     Unconfiguring feature: WMI

[2017-01-09 14:42:34:0913  Warning BtsCfg] BTS management server or DB names are not found in the registry.

[2017-01-09 14:42:34:0913  Info BtsCfg] Entering function: CWMI::StopHostInstance

[2017-01-09 14:42:34:0913  Error BtsCfg] d:\bt\52584\private\source\setup\btscfg\btswmi.cpp(1551): FAILED hr = c0c024bf

[2017-01-09 14:42:34:0913  Error BtsCfg] The server has not been configured.
To configure the server, run the BizTalk Server Configuration wizard and configure the Group feature.

[2017-01-09 14:42:34:0913  Info BtsCfg] Entering function: CWMI::UnMapHost

[2017-01-09 14:42:34:0913  Error BtsCfg] d:\bt\52584\private\source\setup\btscfg\btswmi.cpp(1696): FAILED hr = c0c024bf

[2017-01-09 14:42:34:0913  Error BtsCfg] The server has not been configured.
To configure the server, run the BizTalk Server Configuration wizard and configure the Group feature.

[2017-01-09 14:42:34:0913  Info BtsCfg] Instantiating IBTSMsgBoxPerformance object

[2017-01-09 14:42:34:0929  Info BtsCfg] Calling IBTSMsgBoxPerformance::UninstallArtifacts
Exception in CounterManager.UninstallArtifacts when uninstalling the perf counter instances. The exception details are: 
Source of exception: System
Message: Cannot delete Performance Category because this category is not registered or is a system category.
Stack trace:    at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Delete(String categoryName)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.MsgBoxPerfCounters.MgmtDbAccessEntity.UninstallInstances(Boolean regularUninstall)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.MsgBoxPerfCounters.CounterManager.UninstallArtifacts(Boolean regularUninstall, String logFileName)

[2017-01-09 14:42:34:0929  Info BtsCfg] Stopping Tracing

[2017-01-09 14:42:34:0929  Info BtsCfg] Entering function: CWMI::DeleteServer

[2017-01-09 14:42:34:0929  Error BtsCfg] d:\bt\52584\private\source\setup\btscfg\btswmi.cpp(1351): FAILED hr = c0c024bf

[2017-01-09 14:42:34:0929  Error BtsCfg] The server has not been configured.
To configure the server, run the BizTalk Server Configuration wizard and configure the Group feature.

[2017-01-09 14:42:34:0929  Info BtsCfg] Entering function: CWMI::UnConfigureGroup
[2017-01-09 14:42:34:0929  Error BtsCfg] d:\bt\52584\private\source\setup\btscfg\btswmi.cpp(1074): FAILED hr = c0c024bf

[2017-01-09 14:42:34:0929  Error BtsCfg] The server has not been configured.
To configure the server, run the BizTalk Server Configuration wizard and configure the Group feature.

[2017-01-09 14:42:34:0929  Info BtsCfg] Leaving function: CBtsCfg::UnConfigureFeature

[2017-01-09 14:42:34:0929  Info BtsCfg] Leaving function: CBtsCfg::ConfigureFeature

[2017-01-09 14:42:34:0929 Warning Configuration Framework]Feature failed to configure: WMI.

[2017-01-09 14:42:37:0058 Info Configuration Framework]Configuration Summaries:

[2017-01-09 14:42:37:0058 Error Configuration Framework]Feature: [Group] Failed to configure with error message [Exception of type 'System.EnterpriseServices.TransactionProxyException' was thrown.]

[2017-01-09 14:42:37:0058 Error Configuration Framework]Feature: [BizTalk Runtime] Failed to configure with error message [Feature is skipped due to dependent feature (Group) failed to configure correctly.]

[2017-01-09 14:42:37:0058 Error Configuration Framework]Feature: [BAM Tools] Failed to configure with error message [Feature is skipped due to dependent feature (Group) failed to configure correctly.]

[2017-01-09 14:42:37:0058 Error Configuration Framework]Feature: [BAM Portal] Failed to configure with error message [Feature is skipped due to dependent feature (Group) failed to configure correctly.]

Comment: This doesn't seem like the first error you would've gotten in the log.  Are there other errors/warnings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the two machines have different CID:
How to check: Download and run DTCPing tool, if they are the same, you would see warning like: WARNING: the CID values for both test machines are the same.

And then you can see error during Group configuration:
Failed to configure with error message [Exception of type ‘System.EnterpriseServices.TransactionProxyException’ was thrown.]

Resolve: re-install MSDTC in one of two machines:
Run in command line:

```
msdtc –uninstall
shutdown -r -t 00
msdtc -install
net start msdtc
```

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure Windows Firewall is not running, or at least not blocking MSDTC. I would turn it off entirely to rule it out, and then turn it back on and fine-tune what it is allowing if you really want Windows Firewall running.

Comment: This was the case for me. I already re-installed MSDTC on both machines and DTCPing worked just fine even when Windows Firewall was running. Only the configuration itself seems to give this error...(i believe).

Answer (score -2):

Uninstall the BizTalk setup and re-install and then try to configure it.